# $x^6+x+a=0$ has a zero or two distinct solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $m \geq 3$ be an odd integer. Prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, the equation $x^6+x+a=0$ has a zero or two distinct solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$.

I have proven the following facts:

Let $a>1$ be an integer. For any positive $n,d\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\,$ $d$ divides $n$ if and only if $a^d-1$ divides $a^n-1$. In particular, $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

Let $\phi$ denote the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^p$ on the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Then $\phi$ gives an isomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ to itself. Also, $\phi^n$ is the identity map and no lower power of $\phi$ is the identity.

For any prime $p$ and any nonzero $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ prove that $x^p-x+a$ is irreducible and separable over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

I don't know if any of these facts will help me prove this. I am currently studying Chapter 13 from Dummit and Foote. Any help on how to prove the statement is greatly appreciated, thank you.

***My question is not exactly the same as the post in [Number of solns of $x^6+x=a$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, where $m\geq 3$ is odd is same as number of solns of $x^2+ax+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258556/number-of-solns-of-x6x-a-in-mathbbf-2m-where-m-geq-3-is-odd-is-sa)  because I found a counterexample for $x^2+ax+1=0$ having the same number of solutions as $x^6+ax+1=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ whenever $m \geq 3$ is odd.

Comment: Are you sure the wording of the prblem statement is correct? What is the difference between a *zero* and a *solution* in this context?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Shouldn't a zero and a solution refer to the same thing? I have not heard of different definitions for each.

Comment: mercio's answer to the linked question gives a solution to this